# Is there a cross reference for selenium bindings between, say, java and python?

Tags: selenium, binding, webdriver

I find that many answers to selenium webdriver questions are answered in by java programmers or jscript or (your language of choice).  This begs the question, as it is precisely the syntax that is at issue in most of my questions.  Is there a cross-reference that relates the python binding syntax to java syntax, etc.?

Searched till my left index finger is worn to the knuckle.

Comment: A comprehensive matrix of binding-specific features/differences in selenium-webdriver?  I'd be interested in seeing one...

Answer (score 0):

The basic concepts between the different language bindings are the same if not very similar. I started with Java then moved on to C#. I answer questions in python and other languages from time to time because probably 90% of the functionality is the same between the bindings, the real difference is the syntax and that can be looked up in the docs for the target language. I don't know of any such cross-reference, I just read the question and generally know how to answer it and a quick stop in the docs for the target language gets me what I need to answer it.